# Match value of an ini property

Tags: javascript, regex, ini

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070558/regex-to-match-ini-value), I asked how to match a part of the property of an ini value.
I got answered and it works great with a positive lookahead.

Now, I'm trying to get the value of a property : (**edit**)

`foo.bar.far.boo =` **`value`**

`foo.bar.far.boo =` **`value`** `"something"`

`foo.bar.far.boo = "something"` **`value`** `"something"`

`foo.bar.far.boo =` **`value`** `; some comments`

**start edit**

I want to match "value" (in bold).

*Any word which is not quoted followed or not, preceded or not by any other string (quoted) and only after the = (the value part)*

**end edit**

So I tried to use a "positive lookbehind" `(?<==\s)\w+`, but it doesn't exist in javascript.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

By the way, I can't work the value to reverse the string, as I can't access it, I need to return a regex to match, that's the only thing I can do.

**start edit**

I can't work with the value, because I've no access to it. I'm creating a plugin a for a script, and I can only do something like that :

```
return /myregex/;
```

without having access to the actual value.

**end edit**

Comment: and each time result should be "value", or for second one result should be "value other value" ? and for third comments included?

Comment: Edited to avoid this confusion, I only need to match the "first" value (in bold) which is not quoted an can be followed or preceded by another string, in fact I need to match any string which not quoted and preceded by = (the value part)

Comment: can you tell us more about how are you going to use regexp? i.e. why can't you work with array result of regexp (can you?)? Maybe there is something else to do to make it work..

Comment: @Maxym, I edited the question to answer

Comment: I see, but this is not enough for me ;) maybe it leads nowhere, but as I understand you have some script written not by you, it takes a regexp somehow, and make all other stuff. Can't you extend that script, inherit and override that part to work with arrays (i.e. it takes last element of array and treats it as value). Does that script has well known "interface" so you can use e.g. AOP to change that behavior? Otherwise, imho, you won't get value as it is, without array... But it would be interesting if somebody can write such a regexp.. So I would suggest to investigate that script

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** - If the PCRE is compatable with Perl 5.10, this would work:
`/=\s*(?:".*?"\s*)*\K\w+/`

Have you tried `/(?==\s*(?:".*?"\s*)*(\w+))/`  ?
The capture mechanism should grab just the value () in the look ahead, but I'm not sure on JS.

Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ary = (

'foo.bar.far.boo = value1',
'foo.bar.far.boo = value2 "something"',
'foo.bar.far.boo = "something" value3 "something"',
'foo.bar.far.boo = value4 ; some comments',
'foo.bar.far.boo = ; some comments value5'
);

for (@ary) {
#    if ( /(?==\s*(?:".*?"\s*)*(\w+))/ ) {
#        print "'$1'\n";
# or, >= Perl 5.10 ...
    if ( /=\s*(?:".*?"\s*)*\K\w+/ ) {
        print "'$&'\n";
    }
}
```

`'value1'`
`'value2'`
`'value3'`
`'value4'`

Comment: While this extracts the value, the problem is that it returns an array with the first element being empty and the second one being the value. But it is definitely a step in the right direction :)

Comment: @Felix Kling - well then if its just returning a match string, then this is impossible due to the invariability of look behind. Starting in Perl 5.10 using \K stops the preceeding match so far, to be exluded. So `/=\s*(?:".*?"\s*)*\K\w+/` will see the match variable $& equal to just the \w+ part. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit - modified,**

I think I have found a satisfactory answer using just look aheads. The conditions are if the ini line is the proper form, it will suceed and return a single value in the match variable. It will be hard to make it fail. However, a return of `''` could indicate either the value didn't pass form, it passed form but is legitemately `''`. Either way, the regex accounts for failure conditions and returns a `''` as this makes sense.

Here are two variations of the same thing:

`# Variation 1: first 'value [value [value [value ...]]]'`
`/^(?!.*=)|(?:(?==\s*(?:;|(?:\W*"[^"]*"\W*)*$))|\b(?:\w+\s*)+\b(?:(?=\s*;.*$)|(?=\s*(?:[^"=]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)))/`

`# Variation 2: first 'value'`
`/^(?!.*=)|(?:(?==\s*(?:;|(?:\W*"[^"]*"\W*)*$))|\b\w+\b(?:(?=\s*;.*$)|(?=\s*(?:[^"=]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)))/`

A Perl code test case:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ary = (
'foo.bar.far.boo =  value0  ',
'foo.bar.far.boo = value10  ;  value11 ; more comments',
'foo.bar.far.boo = value2 "something2"',
'foo.bar.far.boo = value30 value31 "something32" value33 "something34"',
'foo.bar.far.boo = value4 ; some comments4',
'foo.bar.far.boo = ; some comments50 value51',
'foo.bar.far.boo = "something60" value61 "something62" value63 "something64"',
'foo.bar.far.boo    some comments70 value71',
'foo.bar.far.boo = ',
'foo.bar.far.boo = "junk90"  ,,  "junk91"',
);

for (@ary)
{
 if ( /
       ^ (?! .*=)
     |
       (?:
           (?= =\s*(?:;|(?:\W*"[^"]*"\W*)*$ ))
         |
            \b (?:\w+\s*)+ \b
            (?:
                (?= \s* ; .* $)
              | (?= \s* (?: [^"=]* "[^"]*" [^"]* )* $)
            )
        ) /x )
 {
    print "'$&'\n";
 }
}
```

Output:

`'value0'`
`'value10'`
`'value2'`
`'value30 value31'`
`'value4'`
`''`
`'value61'`
`''`
`''`
`''`